# What is a "rough draft" in Latin?

Tags: vocabulary, english-to-latin-translation, modern-life

Suppose I'm preparing a speech for the Senate floor, and I want to make sure it sounds just right before I present it. So I come up with a rough draft, then revise it several times until I'm satisfied with the way it reads.

What would I call this draft in Latin? Searching through L&S only turns up words for military conscriptions, not unfinished versions of writings, but I'm sure the concept was familiar to the poets and orators.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For adumbratio L/S gives this citation:

> Fig., a sketch, outline: nulla est laus oratoris, cujus in nostris
> orationibus non sit aliqua, si non perfectio, at conatus tamen atque
> adumbratio, * Cic. Or. 29

Comment: Nice find! I think, though, that I might prefer *conatus* to *adumbratio* in this particular instance, or even *conatus primus*.

Answer (score 4):

There *has* to be something somewhere in Cicero …

What I did find, although it is perhaps not an exact match, is [this part in *Brutus*](https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/cicero/brut.shtml#164) where he talks about orations by Crassus that were preserved in written form and remarks that the record was incomplete:

> Plura etiam [sunt] dicta quam scripta, quod ex quibusdam capitibus expositis nec explicatis intellegi potest. Ipsa illa censoria contra Cn. Domitium collegam **non est oratio,** sed quasi **capita rerum et orationis commentarium paulo plenius.** Nulla est enim altercatio clamoribus umquam habita maioribus.
>
> *Also, more was said than was written down, which can be seen from a number of headers which were put down and then not elaborated. And that censorial speech against his colleague Cn. Domitius is **not the speech,** but more like a **list of headlines and a slightly fleshed-out sketch of the speech.** For never has there been a verbal exchange that was conducted under greater clamour.*

… or sketchbook, notebook, collection of notes, exposition, however you want to translate *commentarium*. [I was a bit audacious translating *non est oratio* as “not the speech” (that was held, that is); other translators prefer something like “not really a speech.” Well, that's what you get for not having articles, Romans!]

So **commentarium orationis** might carry the meaning of “rough draught” as well.